# JavaFX: How do you display the contents of a String[] in a TableColumn?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class for movies. The actors are saved in a String[]. I created a GUI with the SceneBuilder. I am setting the values of each TC like so:

```
    tableDirector.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Director"));
    tableActors.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(("actors")));
```

That works for all the non-Collections stuff, but I cannot for the love of everything that's holy figure out how to put several Strings from a String[] in a single Column. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the code you haven't shown is correct, you can do

```
tableActors.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Movie, String[]>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String[] actors, boolean empty) { 
        super.updateItem(actors, empty);
        if (empty || actors == null) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(String.join(", ", actors));
        }
    }
});
```

A more sophisticated cell factory might produce a cell that displayed the actors in a `ListView`, or some similar option.

Note that the `cellFactory` is in addition to the `cellValueFactory` you have already defined.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for. I had forgotten about overriding updateItem. That was the missing link, you are a lifesaver!